# Why does C++ Builder and Delphi class names begin with the letter T?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Like classes TObject, TForm, TComponent.

Why do they begin with the letter "T"?

What is the meaning of "T"?

Comment: Can you give as a code sample to clarify what you mean?

Comment: This is [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) used by Borland (which initially was developing those products). That's it. At that time this notation was quite popular, nowadays when IDE capabilities are greatly improved this notation is considered obsolete.

Answer (score 17):

`T` stands for "type", and it is used as a conventional prefix for non-built-in types in general, not only for class types:

```
type
  TFileName = type string; // string
  TErrorCode = 1..100; // subrange type
  TCarSize = (csSmall, csMedium, csLarge); // enumeration
  TCarSizes = set of TCarSize; // set
  TPersonRec = record // record
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Age: Integer;
  end;
  TSuperBitmap = class(TBitmap) // class
    {...}
  end;
  TDeviceData = array[0..1023] of Byte; // static array
  TLogProc = procedure(const AMessage: string; AKind: TLogKind); // procedural type
  // and so on
```

However, the conventional prefixes for pointer types, exception types, and interface types are `P`, `E`, and `I`, respectively:

```
type
  PPersonRec = ^TPersonRec;
  ESyntaxError = class(EScriptException);
  ISoundPlayer = interface
    {...}
  end;
```

There are several other conventions, like `F` for fields:

```
type
  TCar = class
  strict private
    FModel: string;
    FColor: TColor;
    FWeight: Double;
  end;
```

And `A` for arguments:

```
procedure MyShowMessage(const AMessage: string; AIconType: TIconType);
```

Sometimes people use `L` for local variables:

```
procedure MyShowMessage(const AMessage: string; AIconType: TIconType);
var
  LCaption: string;
  LIcon: HICON;
begin

end;
```

Comment: But not TString or TInteger :-)

Comment: These should also fit into your list: `I` for interfaces and `Co` for COM class factories.

Comment: Fun fact: some users here on Stack Overflow interested in `delphi` tag use `T` prefix in their nick names. [@OndrejKelle a.k.a. TOndrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11480/ondrej-kelle), [@TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama).

Comment: @PeterWolf: And `E` for exception types and `P` for pointer types. I've added those. There's also `S` for string constants and resourcestrings.

Comment: I've seen use of underscore `_` for global variables.

Comment: May also be worth noting that it's not a requirement, but helps you visually understand your code.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I hope that is suggested by the keywords "convention" and "conventional".

Comment: @PeterWolf Right, I used to have "just another Delphi type" in my various profiles ;-)

Comment: @JerryDodge `G` is also commonly used for globals. And `C` for constants

Comment: @Remy Yes I recalled that after my comment, but didn't bother to go back and add it. But the general idea is that it's not mandatory, but is a big help to differentiate things.

Comment: I've noticed some third-party API implementations ignore the naming / prefix conventions and try to perfectly match the internal API names. Especially if that API is also native to the same platform yet written in an entirely different language.